# map env vars to nested appsettings

Tags: asp.net, docker

I have the following nested data in the `appsettings.json`:

```js
{
  "Jwt": {
    "PublicKey": "...",
    "PrivateKey": "..."
  },
  ...
}
```

And the goal is to run this app in WSL/Docker/etc.
so basically I want to override this config nested with environment variables

I've tried to use `"Jwt:PublicKey"` as a variable name, but it doesn't work.

What is the general approach for the env vars storage the way they're able to be mapped to nested configuration?

P.S. actually I store keys in user secrets (`secrets.json`), but it's kind of irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) you can set environment variables like this: `Jwt__PublicKey`.

This would go in your `Dockerfile` under `environment` section:

```
environment: 
      - Jwt__PublicKey=publickey
      - Jwt__PrivateKey=...
```